# Can I make the Olympus OM-D E-M5 control panel always active with one button press?

Tags: camera-controls, olympus, olympus-omd

This camera doesn't seem to have all of direct, physical controls I'd like it to, but it does have a lot of options. There's an "info" screen which gives quick "control-panel" style access to many key photographic options, like focus and drive modes — via touch control, even, if you want.

But, this button doesn't always seem active in every mode, and I can't really figure out exactly when — there's some distinction between EVF mode and rear-LCD live view that I'm not grokking, and there appear to be other factors. Is there a setting or collection of somewhere in the wealth of options that makes the Info button override whatever else is on the screen? I've looked and even read the manual, but it seems like I must missing something.

For bonus points, is there a way to make the controls immediately active when I press Info, rather than requiring me to also press Ok?

And for extra bonus, can I make this display appear in the EVF rather than (or in addition to) the LCD? It'd be nice to not have to take my eye from the viewfinder.

*Failing* all that, is there a clear explanation for when it will work and when it won't? I'd like to devel a more efficient habit than pressing random buttons until it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so, one *can* make this better. The control panel is in fact called the "**Super Control Panel**", which is important to know, because the setting I couldn't find is called `Live SCP` in the menus. And you get to it with a single press of the **`OK`** button, once the camera is configured properly.

The relevant option is in the `Custom Menu`, under page `D` ( which is helpfully labeled "`Disp` / [image: inscrutable glyph] / `PC`" ), in a sub-sub menu named "[image: Camera glyph] `Control Settings`".  Don't be tricked by the "Info Settings" sub-menu below that — that's only for playback.

This is  on page 87 of the manual, and if you look on that page, it just shows a confusing chart of which *possible* control screens are available in which camera modes — P/A/S/M, iAuto, ART, and SCN all have a few different possibilities and can be saved separately. Options include **`Live SCP`** (what we want) and `Live Control` (a point-and-shoot border-menu like quick-access method which basically does the same thing in a different way)

The manual then points back to page 39, which shows how the info button cycles through possible screens. But — and this is key — despite the pictures and the text, it's *not* the info button that brings up the Super Control Panel. It is the `OK` button — *but*, if you have both the SCP and Live Control enabled, Live Control comes up *first*, and you *then* have to push `Info` to switch to the Super Control Panel. (This is the default configuration.)

The manual also points to page 22, where you would have learned what "super control panel" means, were you reading the manual straight through, and also page 24, where you can learn how "live control" differs. Sadly, this is one of those manuals written by someone who already knows what all the functions and menu items do, and it's really only useful once you've already figured it out. Looking at the manual when I was first confused only made things worse – I didn't get this figured out until I sat down and flipped back and forth and went through the camera menus and tried things and then referred back to the manual and then back again.

So, in summary:

**In [image: Camera glyph] `Control Settings` under Custom Menu D, turn `Live SCP` *on* and `Live Control` *off*. Then, pressing the `OK` button while shooting will bring up the Super Control Panel with no fuss.** One can then select an option and change it with a control dial without further button presses, or press okay to go to a sub-menu for that option.

Oh, and [image: inscrutable glyph] looks like it might mean "remote control", but it's actually for "beep sound".

Comment: You have made the same mistake i did - of not realising that the OM-D is merely a decorative accessory to an incredibly challenging cryptographic puzzle game disguised as a manual.