# How do I get the Super Control Panel of Olympus OM-D E-M5 to appear on rear-LCD screen when the EVF is on?

Tags: olympus, olympus-omd, evf

I like having the EVF Auto Switch off (as I don't like the lag in getting the EVF to turn on with the eye sensor), but I would like to get the SCP on the rear-LCD screen.  I read in a blog that if you have the EVF Auto Switch Off and have the EVF on, the SCP will be displayed on the rear-LCD screen if the eye sensor detects that you are not using the EVF.
This would be great, and really the way I would like to use it, but unfortunately it doesn't appear to work like this for me..

Is there an option or something to enable this to work?

I have the latest firmware update (1.2).

Comment: What _does_ the rear LCD display? Nothing, or a different display? (I assume you know or have figured out http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24590/can-i-make-the-olympus-om-d-e-m5-control-panel-always-active-with-one-button-pre already.)

Comment: The latest FW is 1.6

Answer (score 4):

If you didn't noticed there is a button on the right side of the viewfinder |▢|.

[image]

Image source: http://www.trustedreviews.com/olympus-om-d-e-m5_Digital-Camera_reviewsource

First of all there are 2 modes (to quick access this setting, long press the screen button on the side of the viewfinder):

- the viewfinder will turn on automatically. When the auto switch is on you have 2 possible settings. SCP (super control panel) on the screen and viewfinder. Press the button and you will change to live view on the screen, plus the viewfinder.
- the viewfinder will turn on manually. Use the button to change between screen or viewfinder. Either option that you'll choose will keep only the selected screen on. To choose whether if you see live view or the SCP on the screen there is a setting in the camera menu.

Comment: could you please post a credit/link to the image if it's off another site?